Where are fees charged in the execution process?
tracing execution from load_and_execute_sanitized_transactions, the actual invocation of the eBPF VM comes in process_executable_chain which in its body calls vm.invoke_function. This is my understanding of when the ePBF VM is instantitated, and the corresponding program (JIT'd or interpreted is called)
What I don't quite understand is, judging from this question, this process must log the number of ePBF instructions, then charge this as part of the compute budget.
But in the rBPF vm.rs I see the counting of insns here, but I don't see this called in the function chain from load_and_execute_sanitized_transactions to process_instruction.
So I understand that per signature fees are charged prior to execution (I believe in load_commit_transactions or something) but where is the REST of the compute budget charged in execution?

Consuming CUs is done through the InvokeContext, which implements the ContextObject trait at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/6e067fcd28620a32eab8461ad5e5be79e28d41f7/program-runtime/src/invoke_context.rs#L99, and consume is used in the VM at https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/blob/f3758ecee89198433422f751beee7f0f52dbcd55/src/vm.rs#L423 for normal instructions.
Syscalls consume compute units too at https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/blob/f3758ecee89198433422f751beee7f0f52dbcd55/src/program.rs#L331, as implemented for a "builtin" function at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/6e067fcd28620a32eab8461ad5e5be79e28d41f7/programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs#L645
I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I hope it helps!

thank you jon for the answer. one quick q: where is execute_program in rbpf.rs called in the bank?

It's not execute_program, but rather invoke_function on the program's entrypoint at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/96deb8b5e4561fb480759eea389b61323dced1d3/program-runtime/src/invoke_context.rs#L529

so looking at '''invoke_function''' it seems to call wtv is in the VM registry. And that is '''execute_program'''? Apologies here, don't quite understand, because it seems like resource metering is done in '''execute_program'''
